# Confused about how should I work with Redux and Database

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to use Redux in my React Native application.

I use Realm as a local database, and I'm pretty confused about how to implement it.
In Realm, I save an array of custom objects, so when the app starts I want to fetch the array and set it in the state of the app.

As far as I understand, I need to have an action, which looks like this:

```
export const fetchItems = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_ITEMS",
        })
    }
}
```

And have a reducer that looks kinda like this:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.fetchItems:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            }
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But I'm not really sure how should I use this in my Home Screen for example.
I guess it should be something like this:

```
  const { items } = useSelector(state => store.getState().items)
```

But then, when I'm adding a new item to the database, I should of course update the database, so when I should update the state? I tried to read articles, and watch some tutorials, but everyone works a little different and it is even more confusing.
So far, is what I wrote about Redux is right? should be using it like this?

Comment: In your thunk, `fetchItems`, you should get your items from the Realm database and then send them in the payload of the `FETCH_ITEMS` action to save the items in your reducer. Something like this: `export const fetchItems = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        // This is pseudo code, since I don't know how to use Realm
        const realmDbItems = await Realm.table('items')
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_ITEMS",
            payload: realmDbItems
        })
    }
}`

Comment: Maybe a good option would also be to use `observables` and observe your state. So whenever something in your state changes, you also reflect that update into your Realm DB. If you haven't already, take a look at [redux-observables](https://redux-observable.js.org/)